# How to update some values only in bulk in elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

In elasticsearch I have data something like
`post_en` as index and multiple posts saved in that which has fields like `id, title, description, price, status`.

Now how I can update specific fields only for each post with the use of bulk.
(With single post I can easily update the fields.)

Here is a sample of json for bulk request.

```
{"_index":"post_en","_id":"966156"}
{"id":966156,"status":2}
{"_index":"post_en","_id":"966157"}
{"id":966157,"title":"some title","status":1}
```

Using this json it is updating the given fields but its also removing the other existing fields, meaning whole object is replaced with the given updated object. but i just want to update the given fields and keep remaining fields as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You possibly will have to do update as opposed to insert (doc_as_upsert option)

Quoting the documentation here

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update

> The update action payload supports the following options: doc (partial document), upsert, doc_as_upsert, script, params (for script), lang (for script), and _source. See update documentation for details on the options.

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    }
}
```

Created index with mapping

Indexed 2 documents

```
{"id":966157,"status":2}
{"id":966157,"status":3}
```

Performed a bulk operation

```
{ "update" : {"_id" : "ISpCB4IBCOifrGItSDgU", "_index" : "post_en"} }
{ "doc" : {"status" : "4"} }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "ICpCB4IBCOifrGItKTgF", "_index" : "post_en"} }
{ "doc" : {"status" : "5"} }
```

On search

```json
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "post_en",
                "_id": "ISpCB4IBCOifrGItSDgU",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 966157,
                    "status": "4"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "post_en",
                "_id": "ICpCB4IBCOifrGItKTgF",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 966156,
                    "status": "5"
                }
            }
        ]
```